# ListView with Items from REST service

Tags: android, rest, listview, listadapter

Suppose I want to show items in a ListView. The datasource is a REST API, let's say `www.example.com/getItems?ps=10cp=1`
where ps = pagesize and cp = currentpage. 
The answer gives count = xy, amount of total items. 
Now the amount of total items is, let's say 1000.

What's the best way to load and show those in a ListView? Load all 1000 items from the API, throw them in the ListAdapter? I watched a Google IO talk where they said loading one big chunk of data over the network is better than loading lots of small chunks.

Another possibilty would be to bind every ListItem to the API (kind of like lazy loading images), but that would create a call to the API for every single ListItem, that seems stupid.

A compromise would be to load 100 items, then load 100 more when the user has scrolled to the 100th item, is there some sample implementation to look at? Is that the 'way to go'? What's the best practise here?

Answer (score 1):

Yes I agree with you that it is the way to go.

you can use [endlessadapter](https://github.com/commonsguy/cwac-endless) or [this one](http://benjii.me/2010/08/endless-scrolling-listview-in-android/).

for smooth scrolling the loading of next batch should happen before the scrolling end.